# Which is faster: Writing SQLite database or In a Text File

Tags: android, database, text, sqlite

In Android, for saving persistent data - Which is better for faster writing speed in memory. SQLite Database or in a Text File?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

If you're saving complex data, then SQLite Database is obviously better and scalable.

But if you're saving non complex data like an integer or something, by all means use a text file, afterall SQLite Database is a flat file